# topological navigation slam problem

Tags: ros, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run  topological navigation stack as mentioned in
http://ros.org/wiki/topological_navigation
on Ubuntu 10.04, ROS Diamondback (installed from repository using debs).
On launch, NO errors are reported but Stage GUI do not come up. No other GUI are present as well. The log files do not show termination of stage node or anyother node.

How shall i go forward?
I had tried the fresh installation on second machine as well. I recieve same behaviour from launch file.

Log file can be found at [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?sgh8ivg4j742z2l).
Terminal output can be found at [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?zmu2i9kki106aq4).

nitin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12856/topological-navigation-slam-problem/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I observed just now something which I missed. Stage was being launched headless with -g parameter.
Now Stage GUI do popup!

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0